# Reach functionality from other class c#

Tags: c#

## update

I'm writing a silverlight application and I have the following Class "Home", in this class a read a .xml file a write these to a ListBox. In a other class Overview I will show the same .xml file. I know it is stupid to write the same code as in the class "Home".

The problem is, how to reach these data.

My question is how can I reuse the method LoadXMLFile() from another class?

The code.

// Read the .xml file in the class "Home"

```
public void LoadXMLFile()
    {
        WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
        xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(XMLFileLoaded);
        xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("codeFragments.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
            private void XMLFileLoaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            string xmlData = e.Result;
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

            var tagsXml = from c in xDoc.Descendants("Tag") select c.Attribute("name");

            List<Tag> lsTags = new List<Tag>();
    
            foreach (string tagName in tagsXml)
            {
                Tag oTag = new Tag();
                oTag.name = tagName;
                var tags = from d in xDoc.Descendants("Tag") 
                                       where d.Attribute("name").Value == tagName
                                       select d.Elements("oFragments");
                var tagXml = tags.ToArray()[0];
   
                foreach (var tag in tagXml)
                {                       
                    CodeFragments oFragments = new CodeFragments();                        
                    oFragments.tagURL = tag.Attribute("tagURL").Value;
                    //Tags.tags.Add(oFragments);
                    oTag.lsTags.Add(oFragments);
                    
                }
                lsTags.Add(oTag);
            }
            
            //List<string> test = new List<string> { "a","b","c" };
            lsBox.ItemsSource = lsTags;
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your function downloads XML, but doesn't return it, so the value just gets lost. Not sure what the point of it is.

Comment: That's the whole problem. I don't know how to return the result of my .xml file...

Comment: If you don't know how to write a function so it returns a value, I think you need to pick up a basic C# programming book.

Comment: yes.. not literaly. It's the problem with the delegate there are bouth of type void.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to read the XML file, make references to this from your other classes in order to use it. Say you call it `XmlFileLoader`, you would use it like this in the other classes:

```
var xfl = new XmlFileLoader();
var data = xfl.LoadXMLFile();
```

If I were you, I would make the `LoadXMLFile` function take a `Uri` parameter to make it more reusable:

```
var data = xfl.LoadXMLFile(uriToDownload);
```

Comment: OK. What is the difference between var xfl = new XmlFileLoader(); and XmlFileLoader() xfl = new XmlFileLoader(); . And the method LoadXMLFile() and XMLFileLoaded must these return something?

Comment: The first line is like what you do in your function with `new WebClient();`. It gets a new `XmlFileLoader` object (which I am just using as an example for a class name). The second line uses the first one. Both should return something, as otherwise you won't be able to use the XML...

Comment: I updated the question. I want just the value of variable lsTags (lsBox is the listBox from "Home page"). Is there no other way than create another class for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class whose single responsibility is loading XML and returning it, leaving the class that calls your LoadXmlFile method to determine how to handle the resulting XML.